# jsf commandbutton onclick how to change button value

Tags: jsf

I have a button with value "Add". i need that onclick , the value will change to update and to clean the text filed beside.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrkUB.png)

```
<h:head>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    function changeText(){
           alert('Hi');
           }
</script >
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Conpatible" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="bootstrap.min.css" />     
    <title>Products</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tableUpdated {
            width: 90% !important;
            margin: 17px 58px 0 !important;
        }
        .btnSpace {
            margin: 17px;
        }     
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <center><h2><h:outputText value="Products List"/></h2></center>
        <p>Welcome #{login.user}</p>

       <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Quantity</f:facet>
            <h:inputText id="quantity-id" value="#{product.quantity}"  >
               </h:inputText>
        </h:column>
       <h:column>
             <f:facet name="header"> </f:facet>  
            <h:commandButton action="#{Products.addToBag(product.pname,product.pimg,product.pprice,product.quantity,login.user)}" value="Add"   onclick="changeText()" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
        </h:column>  
<h:commandLink action="#{login.logout}" value="Logout"></h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Please your help
Thanks
Sara

Comment: Tip: don't add images - add code. It'll make our life (and yours) a lot easier

Comment: I tried to add code but i get error msg Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: That's just how the site works. Every line of your code must be preceded by four spaces, and you should also replace every indent (like \t) with another four spaces

Comment: Do not use [java] tag when question is not answerable by Java experts. Do not use [xhtml] tag when question is not answerable by XHTML experts. This question is only answerable by JSF experts. Hence I removed the tags attracting the wrong audience.

Comment: You are missing the <h:dataTable> tag in the xhtml. Please try to edit the question to provide a [mcve] including bean source code. This helps us help you. Hint regarding the question: You should make the commandButton value depend on the server state or even create two buttons. If the entry is present in the bean, render the "Update" button. Else render the "Add" button.

Comment: I am trying to add code . i put spaces. but again and again i get: " Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code)."

Comment: Hi Selaron thanks for hint, i added update button with succes to display/not display but not for the current row in data table, it dispaly for all the datatable.